# Overflow hidden with different elements

Tags: jquery, css

is it possible to hide the exceeding element (i.e. photo) IF the said element is a different element (i.e. not child element) from its frame?

so usually we have frame element and its child like this:

```
<div id="frame">
   <img src="xyz" />
</div>
with css:
#frame {overflow:hidden;}
```

but what if I need the exact same function with this situation:

```
<div id="frame">
</div>
<img src="xyz" />
```

for the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/t7EgU/2/

and this is current result and the result I expect:
http://i44.tinypic.com/hs0yv8.jpg

is there a way to solve this?

thx :)

Comment: you cannot entirely hide your image behind something wich opacty is less than 1 (image or bg color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dragging around the div, you could set the image as a

```
background-image
```

and the set the

```
background-position
```

to move the image around within the div.

In this example, I have the photo element invisible and the "window" I created match it

http://jsfiddle.net/t7EgU/16/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you need to support only modern browser you may use `:not(:empty)`, like so

```
#frame:not(:empty) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

A simple usage demo: http://jsbin.com/egatij/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

or use jquery:

```
if ($('#frame').children().length != 0 ))
$(this).css('overflow': 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the photos you posted this could be a simple z-index issue, if you wanted the frame to be on top give it a higher z-index.

For example:

```
#frame { position:relative; z-index: 2;}
img { position:relative; z-index:1;}
```

But then looking at the jsfiddle you added along with your question, it uses a png so maybe there is a slight opacity on the image itself. Maybe if you re-saved the image with 100% opacity you will, possibly, get the solid frame you were expecting.